# How to interrupt a piped request in Node.js and return a redirect instead?

Tags: node.js, redirect, proxy

I have an endpoint that acts as a proxy to another service of mine, and it essentially pipes GET requests like so:

```
var options = {
        'uri': url,
        'headers': req.headers,
        'method': req.method,
        'time' : true
}

request(options, function(error, response, body){
        if (error){
                ...
        }
}).pipe(res);
```

What I would like to do is to prevent this proxy application following the redirect and returning the full content with a 200 status code, and instead just pass the full redirect back to the initial request.

I've played around with something like this, but it just executes that code after the pipe has already returned the 200:

```
request(options, function(error, response, body){
        if (error){
                ...
        }
        if (response.statusCode == 302){
            res.redirect(302, response.headers.location);
        }
}).pipe(res);
```

Is there a way I can interrupt this pipe process so that I can manually re-send redirects that come back from this proxy request, whilst allowing non-redirects to continue as usual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you'd need to assign the readable stream to a variable and pause the stream until the 'response' event is emitted. Then you either do the redirect or continue piping the response. Something like this should work (can't test it right now since I'm on mobile):

```
const requestStream = request(options);
requestStream.pause();
requestStream.on('response', (response) => {
    if(response.statusCode === 302) {
        // destroy the readable stream to prevent leaking
        requestStream.destroy();
        return res.redirect(302, ...)
    }
    requestStream.pipe(res);
    requestStream.resume();
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I will give that a try later :-)

Comment: Just tried it now, it's not working because the statusCode is still coming back as a 200.

Comment: Can you try adding `followAllRedirects: false, followRedirect:false` to the request options?

Comment: By jove, I do believe that has worked :-) Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help!